# TypeScript indexer for static class

Tags: typescript, static, indexer

Basically what I'm trying to do is getting a value from a static class. Like this:

```
export enum Test {
    A = 10,
    B = 20,
    C = 30

}

export class TestObject
{
    constructor(public ValueA: string, public ValueB: Date){}
}

export class TestValues {
    [key: number] : TestObject;
    public static 10: TestObject = new TestObject ('AAA', new Date());
    public static 20: TestObject = new TestObject ('BBB', new Date());
    public static 30: TestObject = new TestObject ('CCC', new Date());
}

var a = Test.A as number;
var result = TestValues[a];
```

This wil return the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because
type 'typeof TestValues' has no index signature.
```

See typescript playground [HERE](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXKBvAUFTUCCUC8UAjAAwA0GWAQvlAExkWYDCNAzMWmgL6cDGANgEN48WAkQB5AEYArYL0Rp0WKLwD2IJACcwCtVoAUABzBT+AS15QAaoP5hg2AFxRt5kAHNSUE2cs27B0oXABFBRGAAShQeHjQBYVE4JFt7BFRGKABtAGtgAE8XcAgpYC0AXSgXZMlZeUQAbkzfCyskcP8SavFpOQUaEGAAdzEkXvqoAwBybFmp70GRsIiDSMimlRb-dsR-em6xuv6CRdHavuRpymv5qFPl4FX15tNW10QOq3YD84mT4bO4360yYoNu93CjzWTTiADdBFooIIaDUAHS4YR3SClLRNeGIrQIMD8ZAEGqpBzwLKCcoNIA)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I fixed it by not exporting the static class anymore. I made it a normal class that I instantiate and export as a constant.

**ANSWER:**

```
export enum Test {
    A = 10,
    B = 20,
    C = 30

}

export class TestObject
{
    constructor(public ValueA: string, public ValueB: Date){}
}

class TestValuesDefinition {
    [key: number] : TestObject;
    public 10: TestObject = new TestObject ('AAA', new Date());
    public 20: TestObject = new TestObject ('BBB', new Date());
    public 30: TestObject = new TestObject ('CCC', new Date());
}

export const TestValues = new TestValuesDefinition();

// And than in the other file
var a = Test.A;
var result = TestValues[a];
```